# jquery formatcurrency error on IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency, caret

I'm having a problem on IE and Chrome when using the jQuery Format Currency and the jCaret plugins.

The problem is described here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/issues/detail?id=23&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Opened

When using the fix shown there, format as you type only works on Firefox. On other browsers the cursor stays "blocked" on the input control and you can't select other control. It seems the focus() event is looping.

I've created a jsFiddle to test this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/B3xA6/4/

Help is appreciated on getting this to work (especially on IE).

Thank you